# ¿Como puedo validar que un INPUT TEXT acepte solo 1 palabra y numeros?

Tags: javascript, html

estoy necesitando un código para validar que en un input solo me acepte una palabra "item" + números, es decir solo me acepte esos filtros, y poder enviar una alerta a usuario que ingrese en ese input.

ejemplo:

item123

Comment: Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Usa el [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78) [y las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar expresiones regulares para poder validar el texto ingresado. Te dejo cómo quedaría el código javascript con la validación.

```js
function validar(evt) {
  var exp = /^item\d+$/;
  var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  evt.preventDefault();

  if (exp.test(nombre)) {
    alert("Valido");
  } else {
    alert("Invalido");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Prueba</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="nombre">
    <button onclick="validar(event)">Enviar</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, este código funciona perfectamente, es l que necesitaba

Comment: La misma validación que estás realizando por medio de Javascript puedes realizarla con HTML, simplemente aprovecha los nuevos atributos que ofrece la versión 5: <input type="text" name="code" required pattern="item\d+">

Answer (score 1):

Aunque tu pregunta no está bien formulada te diré una forma de hacerlo.

Eso que quieres hacer se llama validación de campo de texto a caracteres alfanuméricos y puedes usar [expresiones regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) para esto, una especie de patrones para encontrar una determinada combinación de caracteres dentro de una cadena de texto.

Acá te dejaré un ejemplo suponiendo que quieres validar un formulario para enviar datos:

```js
var texto = document.getElementById("text").value;
var er = /[A-Za-z0-9]/;
if (er.test(text)) {
  //alert("Expresion regular es aceptada");
} else {
  //alert("expresion regular no aceptada");
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Expresiones regulares</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder='Texto' id='text' name='text'>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ahí tienes un ejemplo de como hacerlo, solo te queda acomodarlo a tus necesidades y empezar a conocer un poco más las expresiones regulares y cómo usarlas, sobretodo en JavaScript que son aveces muy necesarias para la validación de formularios.

Si esta es la respuesta que andabas buscando o es la que más te convence, márcala como aceptada. Saludos.

Comment: Tu input acepta todas las letras y caracteres especiales

Comment: Gracias, no me di cuenta de la palabra específica, pero bueno ahí el tiene el ejemplo, solo debe de crear la expresión regular acorde a lo que busca.